# Register account with Net::XMPP

Tags: perl, xmpp

I try to register new account with this code:

```
my @result = $client->RegisterSend(
    to => 'server',
    username => 'user',
    resource => 'res',
    password => '123456'
    email => 'e@ma.il'
);
```

But it return 403 forbidden. Register option is enabled on my ejabberd server and other clients (like pidgin) can create account. Why it doesn`t work in perl?

Comment: We need some more information than that. 403 is a server side error, so it probably isn't your code. Unless you're getting something wrong in your auth.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the following in your configuration file:

- Make sure registration is enabled and open to everyone:

  ```
  ###   ============
  ###   ACCESS RULES
  access:
  ...
    ## In-band registration allows registration of any possible username.
    ## To disable in-band registration, replace 'allow' with 'deny'.
    register: 
      all: allow

  modules: 
    mod_register: 
      welcome_message: 
        subject: "Welcome!"
        body: |-
          Hi.
          Welcome to this XMPP server.

      ip_access: trusted_network
      access: register
  ```
- Make sure you obey the ip_access rules.
- Make sure you do not try register in mass and violate the rate moderation of the registration per ip (check the value of the global `registration_timeout` parameter).

Reference: [ejabberd documentation: mod_register](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#modregister)